# обновление ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте. Есть ViewPager в нем находятся кастомные ListView. Когда зажимаю на item ListView(a), то открывается контекстное меню, где могу удалить данный item, проблема в том, что когда удаляю item, то нормально удаляются свежесозданные item списка, а когда закрываю и заново открываю приложение, то при попытке удалить item он не показывается, что удалился и часть списка появляется на соседней странице ViewPager(a). Для обновления адаптера использую notifyDataSetChanged, но в чем может быть проблема не понимаю.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
final int CTX_MEXU_DEL = 1;
final int CTX_MEXU_CHANGE = 2;
static final String NEW_CHANGE = "NEW_CHANGE";
ArrayList<Predmet> itemList = new ArrayList<Predmet>();
MyAdapter boxAdapter;
DBHelper dbHelper;
static ListView myListView;
Intent intent;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor c;
View v;
static int pageNumber, pos;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
    pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return pageFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    intent = new Intent(inflater.getContext(), PredmetActivity.class);
    v = view;
    // со3даем адаптер
    fillData(pageNumber);
    boxAdapter = new MyAdapter(inflater.getContext(), itemList);
    // настраиваем список
    myListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    myListView.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(myListView);
    //MainActivity.fab.attachToListView(myListView);
    return view;
}

//генерируем данные для адаптера
void fillData(int pos) {
    // делаем запрос всех данных из таблицы mytable, получаем Cursor
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getContext());
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    c = db.query(PredmetActivity.DN[pos], null, null, null, null, null, null);
    // ставим позицию курсора на первую строку выборки
    // если в выборке нет строк, вернется false
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int chislColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("chisl");
        int znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("znam");
        int type_chisl_znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("type_chisl_znam");
        int prepod_chislColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("prepod_chisl");
        int prepod_znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("prepod_znam");
        int kabinet_chislColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("kabinet_chisl");
        int kabinet_znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("kabinet_znam");
        int korp_chislColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("korp_chisl");
        int korp_znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("korp_znam");
        int lect_pract_laba_chislColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("lect_pract_laba_chisl");
        int lect_pract_laba_znamColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("lect_pract_laba_znam");
        do {
            // получаем значения по номерам столбцов и пишем все в лог
            itemList.add(new Predmet(c.getString(idColIndex), c.getString(chislColIndex), c.getString(znamColIndex), c.getInt(type_chisl_znamColIndex), c.getString(prepod_chislColIndex), c.getString(prepod_znamColIndex), c.getString(kabinet_chislColIndex), c.getString(kabinet_znamColIndex), c.getString(korp_chislColIndex), c.getString(korp_znamColIndex), c.getInt(lect_pract_laba_chislColIndex), c.getInt(lect_pract_laba_znamColIndex)));
            // переход на следующую строку
            // а если следующей нет (текущая - последняя), то false - выходим из цикла
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CTX_MEXU_CHANGE, 0, "Изменить");
    menu.add(0, CTX_MEXU_DEL, 0, "Удалить");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CTX_MEXU_CHANGE:
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            c = db.query(PredmetActivity.DN[MainActivity.pos], null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.position; i++) {
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                intent.putExtra(NEW_CHANGE, "CHANGE");
                intent.putExtra("POS_ITEM", Integer.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"))));
            }
            dbHelper.close();
            startActivity(intent);
            return  true;
        case CTX_MEXU_DEL:
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.d("!!!!!!", PredmetActivity.DN[MainActivity.pos]);
            c = db.query(PredmetActivity.DN[MainActivity.pos], null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.position; i++) {
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                int delCount = db.delete(PredmetActivity.DN[MainActivity.pos], "id = " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id")), null);
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "deleted rows count = " + delCount);
            }
            dbHelper.close();
            Snackbar.make(v, "Предмет удален", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            itemList.clear();
            fillData(MainActivity.pos);
            boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return  true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Без кода вам здесь вряд ли помогут

Comment: в том, что у вас `ListView myListView;` - статический, есть какой-то смысл?

Comment: Смысла в этом нет, осталось после небольших экспериментов